# ASP.NET nHibernate+Quartz.NET+Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, unity-container, quartz.net

I am developing a web application to ASP.NET MVC. To interact with the data repository is used, based on nHibernate. Repositories are instantiated through Unity. To repository resolved ISession per request.

Now I need to add to the project crawlers performing periodic scheduled tasks in the background. To implement a crawler selected Quartz.NET. A project can have several different walkers, while interacting with the database through the repository, if matches the execution of their tasks.

The problem is that the crawler must create another session, because it is based on a request solution is not working (no web request). It was implemented a solution in which I register two different implementations of the ISession, but it does not work. The code samples below.

The following questions arise:

1. This is correct direction of solving the problem?
2. How to implement it correctly?
3. Will not this approach two crawler trying to write to the database, to cause mistake?

Code:

```
public class DatabaseRepositoriesRegistration : IUnityRegistration
{
    public void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // web
        var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SessionManager.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        container.RegisterType<ISession>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => SessionManager.CurrentSession)
           );

        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, NHibernateUnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(NHibernateRepository<>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        // externals

        container.RegisterType<ISession>("ext", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c =>
        {
            var config = Fluently.Configure().
            Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration
                    .MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(connectionString)
                    .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                    )
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MappingBeacon>())
            .BuildConfiguration();

            var sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }));

        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(NHibernateRepository<>), "ext", new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISession>("ext")));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SchedulerTask : MvcStartupTaskBase
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public SchedulerTask(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        var scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
        scheduler.JobFactory = new UnityJobFactory(container);
        scheduler.Start();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<UploadConvertionTask>().Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    public class UnityJobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;

        public UnityJobFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            return (IJob)container.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType, "ext");
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UploadConvertionTask: IJob
{
    public UploadConvertionTask(IRepository<Upload> uploadRepositiory) {
        // for repository session is closed!
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scheduler is set up as a local variable inside the run method. It needs to be a variable that lives around long enough for the scheduler to run the task. Without knowing the details of the whole project, you should set your scheduler to be a singleton that is created when the application starts. Then, reference this singleton instance when you're scheduling jobs.

Ideally, your scheduler should be run as a separate long-running service, such as a windows service.